# Flutter : send JSON data to API get error :NoSuchMethodError: Class 'List<dynamic>' has no instance method 'toMap'

Tags: json, flutter, dart, post

I am trying to create a shopping app by flutter, I create models and add to cart and every thing work very fine. I am trying to send the Wishlist as list to API Uri like this :
Products Model contain toMap() method:

```
class Products {
  final String item;
  final int price;    
  Products({this.item, this.price});    
  factory Products.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Products(
        item: json["item"],
        price: json["price"],
      );    
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "item": item,
        "price": price,
      };
}
```

the provider :

```
import '../models/products.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyProv extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Products> product = [];

  void add_item(item) {
    product.add(item);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void del_item(item) {
    product.remove(item);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  get myProduct => product;

  void rem_all(item) {
    item.clear();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Request page :

```
 var result = myProv.myProduct.map((item) {
                      return {"item": item.item, "price": item.price};
                    }).toList();
                      var url = 'http://10.0.2.2:3308/jiyan/data.php';
              var data = await http.post(
                url,
                headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
                body: jsonEncode(myProv.myProduct.toMap()),
              );
              var response = json.decode(data.body);
              print(response);
```

I get the error mentioned in post title above

```
NoSuchMethodError: Class 'List<dynamic>' has no instance method 'toMap'.
```

How can I solve it ? Why doesn't the app append the toMap() method to the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `toMap()` on `product`, which is a `List` and not a `Product`.
The naming is unfortunate.

You can use `result` that you already created and fix this issue by changing the line to:

```
body: jsonEncode(result),
```

Comment: Thanks you , I get this error :  Invalid response line

Comment: This seems to be a further error, appearing later in the code. Either the http.post request was not successfull or the json.decode() did not work.

Comment: Thank you it is worked correctly after I removed the port 3308 from Uri